# Custom comparator isn't sorting

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator

I'm trying to simulate a CPU scheduler. I have an `ArrayList` of a `Process` class I made. I'm trying to sort this array list by the arrival time of the process. I must be missing something, because when I print my `ArrayList`, nothing happens.

I've been looking through other users posts but I haven't found anything that made sense to me.

Here is my `Comparator` and call to `sort`:

```
class ArrivalTimeComparator implements Comparator<Process> {
    @Override
        public int compare(Process p1, Process p2) {
        return (int) (p1.getArrivalTime()-p2.getArrivalTime());
    }
}

Collections.sort(processArray, new ArrivalTimeComparator());
```

Comment: What is getArribalTime() return type?

Answer (score 4):

This code

```
(int)(p1.getArrivalTime()-p2.getArrivalTime())
```

may suffer from integer operation overflow, thus you can get odd results. If you're using Java 7, use

```
Integer.compare(p1.getArrivalTime(), p2.getArrivalTime()); //or Long.compare
```

If you're working with Java 6 or less:

```
return p1.getArrivalTime() > p2.getArrivalTime() ? 1 : p1.getArrivalTime() < p2.getArrivalTime() ? -1 : 0;
```